# Will a Half Mini PCIe card work in a desktop PCI Express 2.0 slot?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

I have an [Intel DH67BL motherboard](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19487/eng/DH67BL_ProductGuide01_English.pdf). Will a Half Mini PCIe card work in one of the PCI Express 2.0 slots? For example, the following product which is a PCIe Half Mini Card:

http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/centrino-wireless-n-1030-brief.pdf

The reason I ask is that I want to add Bluetooth connectivity to the system via a non-USB method as USB bluetooth is proving unreliable.

Comment: No; It won't; That device will only work with Half-Mini PCI-E slots.

Comment: Even though the size/layout of the pins on the device appears to be the same as the two slots on the board (components B/C as illustrated in the PDF at the motherboard link)?

Comment: Appearing to be identical and being identical are two different things.  There are aparently adapters that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will if you use an adapter:

[image]

Search your favorite computer parts site for "Mini-PCIe to PCIe Adapter".

If it's a half-height Mini-PCIe card, you may need to use tape to secure it to the adapter.

AFAIK there is no difference between a half-height Mini-PCIe card and a full-height one, other than the space provided in the chassis or adapter to mount it.  I am finding hits on "Mini PCI Express half- to full-size adapter" if you'd rather not use tape.